# Airflow: Broken Dag <dag_path> 'project' error

Tags: python, airflow

I've written an `Airflow` `DAG` in `Python` and it is syntactically correct since

- `python dag_file_name.py` runs successfully
- `airflow list_dags` shows up name of DAG in WebUI

---

But WebUI shows error

> Broken Dag dag_path 'project'

---

This is confusing since

- The term 'project' does not appear anywhere in my code
- The tasks when run individually, do just fine

---

My questions are

1. What's causing this error and how to fix it?
2. What is Airflow's recommended way of debugging BROKEN DAGs?

Comment: Might help if you paste your DAG. Also I'd check the webserver UI as it will load all DAGs when it starts (and periodically)...if there's an error it might give you the full stack trace there.

Comment: [This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cloud-composer-discuss/NVnN1wFVShw/AjoltBQtBwAJ) seems related

Answer (score 0):

You can check the stack-trace by running the command:

```
airflow list_dags
```

It is going to show you the list of dags that you currently have, but also, in case that you have an error in Python, there you will see where exactly is the error in the code.